# How do Jehovahs Witnesses Interpret Revelation 1:17&18...who is this text referring to, and what contextual evidence substantiates the interpretation?

Tags: trinity, jehovahs-witnesses

All passages below are quoted from the Watchtower [Online New World Translation](https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/study-bible/books/)...so i make the assumption that it is the latest edition of the scriptures according to Watchtower and therefore accurately correlates with their doctrinal beliefs.

Revelation 1: 17  When I saw him, I fell as dead at his feet.
And he laid his right hand on me and said: “Do not be afraid. I am the First and the Last, 18  and the living one, and I became dead, but look! I am living forever and ever, and I have the keys of death and of the Grave.

Their own Bible clearly articulates that the Book of Revelation is "the Revelation of Jesus Christ" and my understanding is that they do not believe God (Jehovah can die), and yet hear we find in this text it clearly saying

Revelation Ch1:"I am the First and the Last...and i became dead, but look! I am living forever and ever"

Revelation 1:13 is clearly talking about Jesus,

> vs13 "and in the midst of the lampstands someone like a son of man,"

Jesus is the only God figure that is called "The Son of Man" and yet we find in the Old Testament (Exodus 33), the only figure in whom men cannot see and live is that of Jehovah (remember John "fell dead to his feet" in vision)

Exodus 33:17

> Jehovah went on to say to Moses: “I will also do this thing that you
> request, because you have found favor in my eyes and I know you by
> name.” 18  Then he said: “Please show me your glory.”

Exodus 33:20

> 20  But he added: “You cannot see my face, for no man can see me and
> live.”

and if we turn to Zechariah

Zechariah 2:10

> “Shout for joy, O daughter of Zion; for I am coming, and I will reside
> in your midst,” declares Jehovah. 11  “Many nations will join
> themselves to Jehovah in that day, and they will become my people; and
> I will reside in your midst.” And you will have to know that Jehovah
> of armies has sent me to you.

Then we study Isaiah we read the following texts...

Isaiah 41

> 2  Who has raised up someone from the sunrise, Calling him in
> righteousness to His feet, To hand over nations to him And to make him
> subdue kings? Who reduces them to dust before his sword, Like
> windblown stubble before his bow?  3  He pursues them, passing along
> unhindered Over paths that his feet have not traveled.  4  Who has
> acted and done this, Summoning the generations from the beginning? I,
> Jehovah, am the First One; And with the last ones I am the same.”

If as Jehovah's Witness say, Jesus was given the authority and power to create the earth and give life to it, how do they explain the following...

Isaiah 42:5

> This is what the true God, Jehovah, says, The Creator of the heavens
> and the Grand One who stretched them out, The One who spread out the
> earth and its produce, The One who gives breath to the people on it
> And spirit to those who walk on it:

Then we read on how God does not delegate glory that is his only...

Isaiah 42:8

> I am Jehovah. That is my name; I give my glory to no one else, Nor my
> praise to graven images.

A quick Google search shows the definition of Glorifying God to mean - through:

1. Our faith
2. Our Worship
3. Our Actions
   https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/article/3-ways-glorify-god-life/

How can Jesus forgive sins in Matthew 9:1-8 if, in light of the above where Jehovah does not delegate his glory to anyone else, and in Isaiah it says we sin against Jehovah?

Isaiah 42:24

> Who has given Jacob for pillage And Israel to the plunderers? Is it
> not Jehovah, the One against whom we sinned?

and finally, where Jehovah clearly articulates in Isaiah that HE (Jehovah is our Saviour)

> Isaiah 49:26  I will make those who mistreat you eat their own flesh,
> And as with sweet wine, they will become drunk with their own blood.
> And all people will have to know that I am Jehovah, Your Savior and
> your Repurchaser

In light of the above research, how do Jehovah's Witnesses interpret Revelation 1:17&18? Is this Jesus or Jehovah? If it is Jesus (the created being they call "a god"), then how is that possible given numerous statements in Isaiah and Zechariah among a large number of other similar texts where Jehovah God does not allow another god to take on his glory or devotion?

Exodus 20 (Example one other similar text)

> 2  “I am Jehovah your God, who brought you out of the land of Egypt,
> out of the house of slavery.b 3  You must not have any other gods
> besides me.
>
> 5  You must not bow down to them nor be enticed to serve them,for I,
> Jehovah your God, am a God who requires exclusive devotion,

Comment: There are too many questions in this post. Separate them j to different questions.

Comment: As for the question in the title it may be a duplicate of[ [this one](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/75474/23657)]

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/79685/23657. related also

Comment: I don't understand the connection you're drawing between Rev 1:17, 18, and all these other verses. Are you saying that John falling down before Jesus would be a sin according to these other verses (because it would be giving glory that's only due to God to someone else)?

Comment: It would be good if it was a JW who answered it.